# How to set PathIcon data not to fill the path area

Tags: uwp

I want to show the path strokes only, not fill the path.

I couldn't figure it out how to do so.

Simple move and draw command like:

```
<PathIcon Data="F0 M 6 0 A 6 6 180 1 1 0 6"/>
```

fills the path:

[image]

How do I avoid filling the path?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/move-draw-commands-syntax) which has Stroke and Fill properties?

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up using. But I wonder if `PathIcon` could have only  stroke

Comment: @Muzib There's no stroke relevant property for PathIcon. Using the Path is the correct direction.